# What was the Ebola plot in Tom Clancy's Jack Ryan?

Tags: plot-explanation, jack-ryan-tv

In S1E6, Suleiman and his brother excavated an Ebola victims body from Liberia & went to Azerbaijan six months ago. Then he provides the 12 captive Doctors Without Borders including Dr. Daniel Nadler (who's POTUS's friend) with some requested medicines like vitamins etc. When they are rescued and POTUS meets them, Dr. Nadler is shown to be ill. The CIA suspects that all 12 of DWB are infected with Ebola and quarantines everyone including POTUS. While Suleiman plans to infect and kill everyone in quarantine with radiation poisoning using Cesium.

So,

1. Are the 12 DWB infected with Ebola? If yes, then how? They are
   doctors and can identify the medication. So, did Suleiman put Ebola
   virus in the tablets?
2. The 12 DWB aren't infected with Ebola but Suleiman tricks CIA to believe so, so that POTUS and other politicians who interacted with the rescued DWB will be quarantined into one place and then he can kill them all with radiation poisoning. Like he did in Paris. This sounds consistent but Suleiman excavated Ebola victim 6 months ago. DWB are captured just weeks ago.
   How could he know, he would capture DWB and that too Daniel Nadler (POTUS's friend) who will then be used as a pawn in his elaborate scheme to kill POTUS. What did he do with the Ebola then?

So, which one of the two Ebola plots is Tom Clancy's Jack Ryan trying to present?

Or is there a 3rd version I did not deduce from my viewing?

Answer (score 3):

> Are the 12 DWB infected with Ebola?

Yes, they were. This is confirmed in the show.

> If yes, then how? They are doctors & can identify the medication. So, did Suleiman put Ebola virus in the tablets?

Now here we're not sure, it's **implied** that they were infected via the medicines they received but we're not told what form these medications too...they could have been tablets, capsules, liquids any of which could disguise their true nature.

Equally, it could have been some other form of transmission such as contact with infected bedding or in their drinking water.

> but Suleiman excavated Ebola victim 6 months ago. DWB are captured just weeks ago.

The virus was being experimented on for some time before being used in the final plot.

> How could he know he would capture DWB & Daniel Nadler (POTUS's friend) who will then be used as a pawn in his elaborate scheme to kill POTUS. What did he do with the Ebola then?

We don't **know** what Sulieman's *original* plan was for the Ebola virus, presumably he had *some* plan (which would have been bad enough) but, concurrent with his plans to take control of the terrorist organiation, he learns of the DWB doctors which include Dr Nadler and uses them to *extend* his plot to include POTUS.

Comment: I remember a scene where the female doctor (Claire??) inspects POTUS & says that Nadler is doing ok & his condition is stable. You are referring to that scene in your first statement?. I interpreted as he didn't have ebola

Comment: That wasn't my interpretation or that of anyone else's review I can find. They all think the doctors were infected.

Comment: "They" meaning the CIA & the doctors right?

Comment: No...all the other people who reviewed the show. (including Wikipedia) The doctors confirm the POTUS is *not* infected but all they say about Nadler is *"He's not much better, but he's not worse, which is a good thing."* which certainly implies is infected otehrwise they would say he wasn't.

Comment: _"Equally, it could have been some other form of transmission"_ Unlikely. In the same episode that the DWB get their supplies, we see the interview with Cathy (where she finds out Jack is CIA) where she explicitly confirms that transmission is the tricky part of spreading it. And later on, someone specifically questions the vitamin pills that they found in the DWB prison cell. This all suggests that the vitamin pills are the transmission vector. The show never explicitly confirms it but it gives you all the pieces.